# Regarding sed expression evaluation in shell

Tags: linux, shell, sed

Could someone explain the meaning of below sed statement?

```
sed -i "s/PS1\='\\\\u\@[^]]*:/PS1\='\\\\u\@\\\\H:/g" test
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, note that `PS1` is the bash prompt. See [How to: Change / Setup bash custom prompt (PS1)](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/howto-linux-unix-bash-shell-setup-prompt.html) for more references.

```
sed -i "s/PS1\='\\\\u\@[^]]*:/PS1\='\\\\u\@\\\\H:/g" test
```

It looks for the text `PS1\='\\u\@[^]]*:` and replaces it with `PS1\='\\u\@\\H:` in `test` file.

`sed 's/hello/bye/g' file` is the basic sed command that looks for `hello` and replaces it with `bye` all along the `file` (`g` means "global", so it does every time it finds the text).

While this `sed` expression shows the result on stdout, if you want the result to update the file, you add the `-i` option instead.

Then, note that I mentioned that the text looked for is `PS1\='\\u\@[^]]*:`, while in the `sed` expression we see `PS1\='\\\\u\@[^]]*:`. That's why any `\` has to be escaped... and the `\` character is used to do so.

Regarding the specific pattern looked for:

```
PS1\='\\u\@[^]]*:
```

means text like

```
PS1='\\u\@` 
+
any string until the character `]` is found
+
:
```

So it will match texts like `PS1\='\\u\@[hello how are you]:`.

It replaces them with `PS1\='\\u\@\\H:`.

Comment: Could you please elaborate which pattern it replaces with what. example

Comment: Are you sure it's looking for `PS1\='\\u\@[^]]*:` and not `PS1='\\u@[^]]*:` i.e. without escapes in front of the `=` and `@`? I think `\<character>` in the search RE means `a  literal <character>` rather than `<backslash> followed by <character>` as you'd write that as `\\<character>` but I'm not 100% sure how sed treats it if you escape characters like `=` and `@` that don't need to be escaped as they aren't RE meta-characters.