# How to replace PS1 variable in /etc/skel/.bashrc or .bashrc file using sed, awk, or perl?

Tags: linux, bash, perl, awk, sed

**Edit - 06/08/23 - Original Question Kept Substantially the Same**

Thanks to Charles Duffy for providing valuable feedback in comments. The original question occurs in the context of item 1. But based on the feedback it appears that item 2 is the better option for managing system administration tasks. I may open another question or perhaps post some information in my answer here when I finish my research into `perl` and `/etc/profile.d`.

1. Original Question: How to search and replace literal strings in a file, such as `PS1=<string>` in a `.bashrc` file, using `sed`, `awk`, or `perl`?
2. Better question: How to enable desired prompt behavior using script(s) stored in `/etc/profile.d` that automatically execute whenever a user logs in?

Goal is to automate custom bash prompt on Debian PC and DietPi (ARM) Linux systems. The custom prompt inserts a blank line, to separate commands from terminal output, and looks like this but with different colors:

```
root@dpiBox /root
#

user@dpiBox /home/user
$
```

where root@dpiBox is red; user@dpiBox is green; and the present working directory is always shown in blue.

When a new `user` is created then a copy of `/etc/skel/.bashrc` is placed in the user's home directory as `/home/user/.bashrc`. The root user already has a copy made as `/root/.bashrc`.

My original plan was to edit `/etc/skel/.bashrc` via script before adding new users and to manually edit the `/root/.bashrc`. But when root or any user log in this automatically executes scripts properly installed under `/etc/profile.d`. Charles Duffy seems to be advising the use of this feature for better management of system administration challenges!

Relevant lines in default `/etc/skel/.bashrc` and `/root/.bashrc` and `/home/user/.bashrc`

```
# /root/bashtest (simulates default .bashrc)
# /etc/skel/.bashrc
# /root/.bashrc
# /home/user/.bashrc

#force_color_prompt=yes

if [ "$color_prompt" = yes ]; then
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\$ '
else
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$ '
fi
```

Step 1 - Uncomment line to turn on color prompt:

```
force_color_prompt=yes
```

Step 2 - Replace old PS1 (above) with new PS1 (shown here) to customize bash prompt:

```
PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\n\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]\[\033[01;34m\] $(pwd -P) \[\033[00m\]\n\$ '
```

The code `[01;32m\]` is green for `/home/user/.bashrc`. Change this code to `[01;31m\]` which is red for `/root/.bashrc`.

**Step 1 - sed:** good result

/usr/local/bin/bashsed (development script to edit bashtest/.bashrc)

```
#!/bin/bash
# uncomment to force color prompt on
off="#force_color_prompt=yes"
on="force_color_prompt=yes"
sed -i "s|$off|$on|" /root/bashtest
```

`sed` code works with double quotes or single quotes used to define `on` and `off`. The double quotes must be used in the sed command.

**Step 1 - perl:** good result

/usr/local/bin/bashperl (development script to edit bashtest/.bashrc)

```
#!/bin/bash
# uncomment to force color prompt on
perl -i.bak -pe 's/#force_color_prompt=yes/force_color_prompt=yes/' /root/bashtest
```

The `i.bak` switch backs up `/root/bashtest` as `/root/bashtest.bak` then edits the file in place. This command can be used on the command line without using the `i.bak` switch.

**Step 2 - sed:** Bad result for `sed -i "s|$old|$new|" /root/bashtest`

/usr/local/bin/bashsed (development script to edit bashtest/.bashrc)

```
#!/bin/bash
# replace old PS1 with new PS1
# old                                    \[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\
# PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\$ '

old='\\[\\033\[01;32m\\]\\u@\\h\\[\\033[00m\\]:\\[\\033\[01;34m\\]\\w\\[\\033\[00m\\]\\'

# new                                    \n\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]\[\033[01;34m\] $(pwd -P) \[\033[00m\]\n\
# PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\n\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]\[\033[01;34m\] $(pwd -P) \[\033[00m\]\n\$ '

new='\\n\\[\\033\[01;32m\\]\\u@\\h\\[\\033\[00m\\]\\[\\033\[01;34m\\] \$(pwd -P) \\[\\033\[00m\\]\\n\\'

sed -i "s|$old|$new|" /root/bashtest
```

Step 2 the code runs without error, but produces **no results**, when double quotes are used to define `old` and `new`. The code throws an error `` sed: -e expression #1, char 149: unterminated `s' command `` when single quotes are used to define `old` and `new`.

**Edit - 06/08/23 - Comments**

Posted my solution to **Step 2** using `perl` call in a `bash` script.

Based on feedback from Charles Duffy the `perl` solution for **Step 2** can be modified to use literal strings stored as bash environment variables. Relevant information is provided near the top of the page under this link:

https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/021

According to Charles Duffy scripts should run from `/etc/profile.d` when a user logs in to better manage sysadmin tasks. I need to do more research to understand this feedback. Here are two links that might be helpful:

https://serverfault.com/questions/434321/when-are-scripts-inside-etc-profile-d-executed

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/64258/what-do-the-scripts-in-etc-profile-d-do

**Links in Original Question**

I have searched extensively, tried dozens of experiments in the context below, and I cannot make sense of these references:

https://linuxhint.com/replace_string_in_file_bash/

[Why would sed have trouble seeing my PS1 prompt?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55540596/why-would-sed-have-trouble-seeing-my-ps1-prompt)

[Replacement of PS1 variable in .bashrc using Sed or Perl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54599967/replacement-of-ps1-variable-in-bashrc-using-sed-or-perl)

[Regarding sed expression evaluation in shell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18376870/regarding-sed-expression-evaluation-in-shell)

So I need to have my "sed" examined! I would not mind using awk if it does the job, but then I need to see the simple command structure, before inserting the literal strings. Otherwise I always mess up the syntax.

Comment: See [BashFAQ #21](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/021), which discusses tools without `sed`'s drawbacks. Both perl and awk are often better choices.

Comment: That said, in general, _I don't recommend editing files in-place at all_. Much better to make your code source a bunch of tiny separate source files you can just replace in their entirety.

Comment: (That said, this advice above is more coming from lessons I've learned wearing my sysadmin hat, not my developer hat; as such, [unix.se] might be the place to look for practices more than Stack Overflow).

Comment: (you may have seen some distros use `/etc/profile.d` and then have bash scripts source `/etc/profile.d/*.bash`, ksh scripts source `/etc/profile.d/*.ksh`, etc -- that's a solid pattern, because then your scriptlets can be tiny files that just do one thing and are easy to replace with no editing ever needed; and using a shared directory everyone sources files from instead of individual copies off `/etc/skel` also means you don't get divergence between old accounts and new ones).

Comment: For a question that covers the same ground as the FAQ I linked above, see [How to search/replace arbitrary literal strings in sed and awk and perl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54059656/how-to-search-replace-arbitrary-literal-strings-in-sed-and-awk-and-perl)

Comment: I appreciate the sysadmin advice although some of it goes over my head. I suppose it would be better to automate the script for adding a new user where /etc/skel/.bashrc is untouched. Instead the script alters /home/user/.bashrc after the user is added. So far I am learning Debian sysadmin (basics) on several raspberry pi hosts and other PCs in a home lab. I want to automate the setup tasks for new install of dietpi and the first item is to customize the bash prompt. I prefer to see the user and present working directory when I login via ssh. I also prefer to insert a space between commands.

Comment: If you *do* want to edit a file in place, prefer `ed` over `sed -i`

Answer (score 1):

Solved using `perl` instead of `sed` or `awk`. Mostly relied on the following reference:

https://www.perl.com/pub/2004/08/09/commandline.html/

`old` literal string in PS1:

```
\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\
```

`old` string escaped for `perl` match:

```
\\\[\\033\[01;32m\\]\\u@\\h\\\[\\033\[00m\\]:\\\[\\033\[01;34m\\]\\w\\\[\\033\[00m\\]\\
```

`new` literal string in PS1

```
\n\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]\[\033[01;34m\] $(pwd -P) \[\033[00m\]\n\
```

`new` string escaped for `perl` replace operation:

```
\\n\\[\\033\[01;32m\\]\\u@\\h\\\[\\033\[00m\\]\\\[\\033\[01;34m\\] \$\(pwd -P\) \\[\\033\[00m\\]\\n\\
```

Used pattern on command line to debug escape sequences for literal strings:

```
perl 's/old/DummyString/' < ps1old > ps1out; cat ps1out
```

```
# ~/ps1old

#force_color_prompt=yes

if [ "$color_prompt" = yes ]; then
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\$ '
else
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$ '
fi
```

```
perl 's/new/DummyString/' < ps1new > ps1out; cat ps1out
```

```
# ~/ps1new

#force_color_prompt=yes

if [ "$color_prompt" = yes ]; then
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\n\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]\[\033[01;34m\] $(pwd -P) \[\033[00m\]\n\$ '
else
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$ '
fi
```

```
perl 's/old/new/' < ps1old > ps1out; cat ps1out
```

Command line solution with test input file `ps1old` writes result to `ps1out`

```
perl -pe 's/\\\[\\033\[01;32m\\]\\u@\\h\\\[\\033\[00m\\]:\\\[\\033\[01;34m\\]\\w\\\[\\033\[00m\\]\\/\\n\\[\\033\[01;32m\\]\\u@\\h\\\[\\033\[00m\\]\\\[\\033\[01;34m\\] \$\(pwd -P\) \\[\\033\[00m\\]\\n\\/' < ps1old > ps1old; cat ps1out
```

This method writes results to file `ps1out` while testing escape sequence patterns from left to right on literal strings represented by placeholder `old` and placeholder `new`.

When the escape sequence fails file `ps1old` or file `ps1new` is unchanged; file `ps1out` reverts to a copy of the respective input file; and `perl` provides valuable debug information.

When the escape sequence succeeds file `ps1out` shows the dummy string `DummyString` as replacement for portions of `old` or `new` working from left to right to debug escape pattern. This can be done one escape character at a time to isolate syntax errors systematically.

After debugging literal strings for both placeholders `old` and `new` then transfer working results to `bash` script with `perl` calls as shown below.

An improvement might be to write changes to a new file then move that to target `.bashrc` and keep `.bashrc.bak` for backup.

**If this script is run more than once it overwrites the backup copy with the edited version!**

Bash script calls perl

```
#!/bin/bash

# Command line test writes result to ps1out without changing ps1old
# perl -pe 's/#force_color_prompt=yes/force_color_prompt=yes/' < ps1old > ps1out; cat ps1out

# Command line test writes result to ps1out without changing ps1old
# perl -pe 's/\\\[\\033\[01;32m\\]\\u@\\h\\\[\\033\[00m\\]:\\\[\\033\[01;34m\\]\\w\\\[\\033\[00m\\]\\/\\n\\[\\033\[01;32m\\]\\u@\\h\\\[\\033\[00m\\]\\\[\\033\[01;34m\\] \$\(pwd -P\) \\[\\033\[00m\\]\\n\\/' < ps1old > ps1old; cat ps1out

# If script is run two or more times it overwrites previous .bashrc.bak!
# Backup target .bashrc using -i.bak switch to uncomment file in place!
perl -i.bak -pe 's/#force_color_prompt=yes/force_color_prompt=yes/' .bashrc

# Replace old PS1 with new PS1 after testing PS1 escape pattern on command line
perl -i -pe 's/\\\[\\033\[01;32m\\]\\u@\\h\\\[\\033\[00m\\]:\\\[\\033\[01;34m\\]\\w\\\[\\033\[00m\\]\\/\\n\\[\\033\[01;32m\\]\\u@\\h\\\[\\033\[00m\\]\\\[\\033\[01;34m\\] \$\(pwd -P\) \\[\\033\[00m\\]\\n\\/' .bashrc
```

Comment: Shouldn't need to escape for perl at all; you can have perl get the literals right out of the environment -- the BashFAQ link demonstrates as much -- and that way you can parameterize to use arbitrary variables without concern about injection attacks.

Comment: The downside of editing files in `/etc/skel`? If your distro provides that file from a package then a simple update/reinstall of the said package that contains/provides `/etc/skel` and the files inside it would reset/revert back all the changes, just a heads up though.